# What's the difference between reinforcement learning, deep learning, and deep reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

What's the difference between reinforcement learning, deep learning, and deep reinforcement learning? Where does Q-learning fit in?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reinforcement learning is about teaching an agent to navigate an environment using rewards. Q-learning is one of the primary reinforcement learning methods.

Deep learning uses neural networks to achieve a certain goal, such as recognizing letters and words from images.

Deep reinforcement learning is a combination of the two, using Q-learning as a base. But instead of using actual state-value pairs, this is often used in environments where the state-action space is so large that it would take too long for Q-learning to converge. By using neural networks, we can find other state-action pairs that are similar. This “function approximation” allows effective learning in environments with very large state-action spaces.

Comment: Deep reinforcement learning is not just Q-learning based. Policy gradient methods such as Reinforce or Actor-Critic are also used with deep neural nets.

Comment: More generally, "deep learning" in an RL context just refers to using function approximation with neural nets to find a policy.

Answer (score 7):

**Deep learning** is a method using neural networks to make function approximators to solve various problems.
Ex: Learning a function which takes an image as input and output the bounding boxes of objects in the image.

**Reinforcement learning** is a field in which we have an agent and we want that agent to perform a task i.e, goal based problems where we use trial and error learning methods.
Ex: Agent learning to move from one position on grid world to a goal position without falling in a pit present in between.

**Deep reinforcement learning** is a way to solve goal based problems using neural networks. This is because, when we want agents to perform task in real world or current games, the state space is very big.
It takes agent very long time to even visit each state once and we cannot use look up tables to store the value functions.
So, to tackle this problem we use neural networks to approximate the state to generalize the learning process
Ex: We use DQN to solve many atari games.

**Q-learning** : It is a temporal difference learning method, where we have a Q-table to look for best action possible in the current state based on Q value function.
For learning Q values we use the reward and the maximum possible next state Q value.

Q-learning basically falls under Reinforcement learning and its deep reinforcement learning analog is Deep Q network (DQN).

Answer (score 2):

The goal of **machine learning** methods is to learn rules from data and make predictions and/or decisions based on them.

The learning process can be done in a(n) **supervised**, **semi-supervised**, **unsupervised**, **reinforcement** learning fashion.

In **reinforcement learning** (RL), an agent interacts with an environment and learns an optimal policy, by trial and error (using reward points for successful actions and penalties for errors). It is used in sequential decision making problems [1].

**Deep learning** as a sub-field of machine learning is a mathematical framework for learning latent rules in the data or new representations of the data at hand. The term "deep" refer to the number of learning layers in the framework. Deep learning can be used with any of aforementioned learning strategies, i.e.,  supervised, semi-supervised, unsupervised, and reinforcement learning.

A **deep reinforcement learning** technique is obtained when deep learning is utilized by any of the components of reinforcement learning [1].  Note that **Q-learning** is a component of RL used to tell an agent that what action needs to be taken in what situation. Detailed information can be found in [1].

[1] Li, Yuxi. "Deep reinforcement learning: An overview." arXiv preprint arXiv:1701.07274 (2017).

Answer (score 1):

Reinforcement learning refers to finish -oriented algorithms, which learn how to attain a coordination compound objective (goal) or maximize along a particular dimension over many steps. The basic theme behind Reinforcement learning is that an agentive role will learn from the environment by interacting with it and getting rewards for performing actions.

Deep Learning uses multiple layers of nonlinear processing units to extract feature and transformation

Deep Reinforcement Learning approach introduces deep neural networks to solve Reinforcement Learning problems thus they are named “deep.”

Answer (score 0):

There's more distinction between reinforcement learning and supervised learning, both of which can use deep neural networks aka deep learning. In supervised learning - training set is labeled by a human (e.g. AlphaGo). In reinforcement learning (e.g. AlphaZero)- the algorithm is self-taught.

Answer (score 0):

To put it in simple words,

**Deep Learning** - It's uses the model of neural network(mimicking the brain , neurons) and deep learning is used in image classification , data analyzing and in reinforcement learning too.

**Reinforcement learning** - This is a branch of machine learning, that revolves around an agent (ex: clearing robot) taking actions(ex: moving around searching trash) in it's environment(ex:home) and getting rewards(ex: collecting trash)

**Deep-Reinforcement learning**  - This is one among the list of algorithms reinforcement learning has , this algorithm utilizes deep learning concepts.

Answer (score 0):

**Reinforcement learning (RL)** is a type of machine learning that is mainly motivated by the feedback control of systems. RL is usually considered a type of optimal control that learns through interacting with a system/environment and getting feedback. RL usually replaces the computationally expensive dynamic programming methods with single time-step/multi time-step learning rule. Popular temporal difference methods in RL are considered somewhere in between dynamic programming and monte carlo methods. Classic RL methods use tabular algorithms that are not that scalable.

**Deep learning (DL)** is considered crucial part of modern machine learning (classical machine learning usually mean SVM, liner regression etc.). DL uses deep multilayered neural networks (NN) with backpropagation for learning. By using well designed deep NN networks complex input-output relations can be learned. Because of this property of approximating very complex functions DL have been extremely popular in recent years (2010-ish), especially in natural language tasks and computer vision tasks. One of the attractive aspect of DL is that these models can be end-to-end, meaning we do not need to do manual feature engineering. There are numerous types of DL algorithms, like Deep neural networs, convolutional neural networks, GRU, LSTM, GAN, attention, transfromer etc.

**Deep RL** uses deep NN architectures to replace the tabular methods for very high dimensional problems. Informally speaking, the controller is no longer a table look-up rather we use a deep NN as the controller. Because of leveraging deep NN in RL this is commonly known as deep RL.

Answer (score 0):

roughly speaking:
**deep learning** uses deep neural networks to approximate complicated functions.
**reinforcement learning** is a **branch** in machine learning where your learner learns through interaction with environment. It is different from supervised or unsupervised learning.
if you use deep learning to approximate functions in reinforcement learning you call it **deep reinforcement learning**.

Answer (score 0):

**Reinforcement learning** is a type of artificial intelligence that aims to model human-like decision-making. It's based on the idea that humans learn from their actions and reward themselves for doing things that are good, and punish themselves for doing things that are bad. Reinforcement learning algorithms try to replicate this process by changing the value of some variable in response to an action.

**Deep learning** is a type of machine learning model which uses multiple layers of processing to solve problems more effectively than traditional approaches. Deep learning models can be used for image recognition, speech recognition, and translation.

**Deep reinforcement learning** is a type of deep learning model that tries to solve problems by using sequences of actions called episodes to improve over time as well as by comparing results from different episodes. It's also known as Q-learning because it was first described by Richard Sutton in 1997 using the Q function (the fourth derivative).

**Q-learning** is a particular type of deep reinforcement learning algorithm that makes use of Q values (quantified measures) instead of actual rewards or penalties, which means it can be used without having access to real data or rewards/penalties yet still produce useful results